# How to set file creation date?

Tags: java, android

I wrote an application that copies data from one directory to another. 
The problem is: 
It is not preserving file creation date and sets to current date and time. 
I use apache library:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(item, dest, true);
```

How to set file creation date/time on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can set date by setting the last modified date.

```
file.setLastModified(creationDate);
```

You can refer https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setLastModified(long)
for more details.

Comment: Changes nothing in my case